# delete whole row of gridview

Tags: asp.net

how can i delete the whole rows of gridview using code behind c sharp   like

```
+-----+-----+------+
|Col1 | Col2| Col3 |
|     |     |      |
| a   |  1  |   5  |
|     |     |      |
| a   |  2  |   6  |
|     |     |      |
| a   |  3  |   7  |
|     |     |      |
| a   |  4  |   8  |
+-----+-----+------+
```

and I want to delete the whole rows  in the gridview so that it becomes

```
+-----+-----+------+
|Col1 | Col2| Col3 |
|     |     |      |
| a   |  4  |   8  |
+-----+-----+------+
```

only last duplicate row left and all the rest is deleted   (rows are deleted from all the columns of gridview)

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: Share some code. It's hard to tell without looking at how you are trying to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `GridView.DeleteRow()`.  MSDN documentation is here: [GridView.DeleteRow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow.aspx)

Comment: The Gridview displays data, shouldn't he be deleting from the datasource?

Comment: @Nick - Depends on what OP is trying to achieve, I suppose.